# 'UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.' whilst using catch() in the function, can't find the issue?

Tags: node.js, async-await, fetch, try-catch, chatbot

I'm trying to do a async funcion to POST some data, but i get 'UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.' error message even while using catch() to handle the function...
This is my code:

```
login = async () => {
            try {
                let response = await fetch(
                    'http://******', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        UserName: user,
                        Password: password
                    })
                }
                );
                let responseJson = await response.json();
                if (responseJson.status == 200) {
                    console.log('Success')
                } else {
                    console.log('Fail');
                    console.log(responseJson.status)
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        }
```

Even with correct data sent as username and password, I get the "Fail" message.
What could be wrong with this code?

EDIT: also, the log of responseJson.status writes it as "undefined"

Comment: Check the status code that returned by the server. I think It will `201` for post

Comment: ehm... regarding to what @Prathamesh More said... it really depends. 201 is supposed to suggest that a new resource has been created in the backend, but 203 is just as legit, if the resource creation takes longer + a crazy amount of real life software doesn't care and 200, although not very REST-y is a super common response. Now, even if it was 201 indeed, this wouldn't cause the issue described by the OP. You're not throwing any errors or anything in that if-statement. Are you 100% sure that this is indeed the code that throws an error? It looks quite legit to me

Comment: i tried it out first on Postman to check the result and it suposedly returned a 200 code... but i'll check again.

Comment: But anyways, yes, this piece of code is the one that gives me the error :/ the code goes to 'Fail' even tho the data I submitted is 100% correct, and the status code returned says "undefined"

Comment: I also get the error: TypeError: Cannot perform 'get' on a proxy that has been revoked